# How to find Employee with the latest Joining Date in this case

Tags: java, date, compare

I have the List of Employees, I am trying to find the `Employee` with the latest Joining date. This is what i have implemented so far.

**Employee :**

```java
package com;

public class Employee {
    private String accountNumber;
    private String joiningdate;

    public Employee(String accountNumber, String joiningdate) {
        super();
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.joiningdate = joiningdate;
    }

    // setters and getters
}
```

**App :**

```java
package com;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class LatestDueDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

            List < Employee > empList = new ArrayList < > ();

            empList.add(new Employee("1234", "07/11/2020"));
            empList.add(new Employee("1234", "06/12/2020"));

            Employee emp = empList.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getJoiningdate)).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

I know that I need to convert the string date format to Date.

Comment: You have not explained any problem with your code. Say, a particular input which does not work as you expect

Comment: it will not harm anyone if you add `e.printStacktrace()`in the catch block instead of eating the exception.

Comment: Do not use `SimpleDateFormat` or `Date`. They're obsolete. Use classes from `java.time` instead.

Comment: What @MCEmperor says. And don’t represent your joining date as a string in your object. Represent it as a `LocalDate` (just like you don’t represent numbers and Boolean values as strings — I hope).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are sorting by the employee's joining date, but the problem is that your Java class represents this date using a *text* string, not a bona fide `java.util.Date` or equivalent Java 8 class.  If you must stick with text dates, then you should at least represent them in an ISO format, e.g.

```
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();

empList.add(new Employee("1234", "2020/11/07"));
empList.add(new Employee("1234", "2020/12/06"));

Employee emp = empList.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getJoiningdate)).get();
System.out.println("Latest employee joined on: " + emp.getJoiningDate());
```

The above works, because the text date `2020/12/06` will sort after `2020/11/07`.  A better approach might be to either represent the joining date using a proper date type, or to at least convert the text dates to actual date types before sorting the employees.

Comment: You don't use the format anywhere so the code you've given is functionally identical to the code in the question

Comment: @Michael ... and you have zero understanding of my answer.  If you ran it, you'd realize that it _does_ work, because now we are sorting on ISO compliant date literals, which sort properly (whereas the OP's original date strings do not).

Comment: That is not [ISO-compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates). Slashes denote intervals.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert String date into `LocalDate` and compare inside comparator. But I recomend you to use `LocalDate` for `joiningdate` in Employee class then you don't need to parse date string inside comparator to latest joining date one.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
Employee emp = empList.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(e -> LocalDate.parse(e.getJoiningdate(), formatter)))
    .get();
```

Note: Don't use old `Date` class rather use `LocalDate` of `java.time`